# PHP PDO / MySQLi doesn't return rows while query has mysql user-variables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, user-variables

I want to execute and get the results of the following query:

```
$query = <<<SQL
    set @num := 0, @priority := '';
    select * from (
        select
        id, status_ts,
        @num := if(@priority = priority, @num + 1, 1) as _row_number,
        @priority := priority as priority
        FROM ($priority_query) as get_priority
        ORDER BY priority DESC, status_ts ASC
    ) as items where items._row_number <= CEIL(priority);
SQL;
```

The `$sql = $PDO->query($query); $sql->rowCount()` returns 0, there are no result rows. I've tested the query by executing it directly in the DB and it works.

Comment: Just execute only one statement per query.

Comment: I agree with @PaulSpiegel. There is no reason to batch multiple statements into one execution, and it makes code more complicated and harder to debug.

Comment: Haven't though of that very simple answer. :/ Thanks! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go was to make a multiple query, changing `set` to `select` and then properly iterating through the results.

```
$query = <<<SQL
    select @num := 0, @priority := '';
    select * from (
        select
        id, status_ts,
        @num := if(@priority = priority, @num + 1, 1) as _row_number,
        @priority := priority as priority
        FROM ($priority_query) as get_priority
        ORDER BY priority DESC, status_ts ASC
    ) as items where items._row_number <= CEIL(priority);
SQL;
```

## PDO

```
    $sql = $pdo->query($query);

    if ($sql && $sql->nextRowset()) {
        $items = [];
        $numRows = $sql->rowCount();
        if (($numRows > 0)) {
            $items = $sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
    } else {
        $error = $this->DB->pdo->errorInfo();
        throw new \Exception($error[2]);
    }
```

## MySQLi

```
$mysqli->multi_query($query);
$mysqli->next_result();

if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
      printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
   }
}
```